# Generate new IV in Python

Tags: python, bit, initialization-vector

I have a list of 100 bit, for example:

```
X=''.join([random.choice(['0', '1']) for i in range(100)])

X=[0,1,0,1,1...]
```

At the beginning of the cycle, I have been generate random initialization vector with n length:

```
Xlen=5
IV=''.join([random.choice(['0', '1']) for i in range(Xlen)])
```

The problem is I need to generate new IV based on the previous `X[n]` and `IV[n]` using the bit addition function. Note that `n=5`.

For example `X[0]=[0,1,0,0,1]` and `IV[0]=[1,0,1,0,1]`. The new `IV` should be updated to `X[0]+IV[0]=IV[1] which will produce the result of [1,1,1,1,0]`.
`X[0]` and `IV[0]` is the list of bit and initialization vector at cycle 0.
And operation of generating new IV will be continuously repeated for the next `n=5` until `n=100`.

Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Your list as you declare it here contains one element, a rather large integer. Are you sure that's what you have? (since it conflicts with your text)

Comment: Thats probably a string (wouldn't make sense for an int to start with 0?)

Comment: Your question heavily implies that `IV[0]` is a single digit, yet you also say `IV[0]=10101`.  Which is it?

Comment: @RafaelC: You're right, it does not make sense. So OP should clarify exactly what he has, rather than leave us guessing.

Comment: @Amadan Actually it is the list of bit in an array.
@ John Gordon..`IV[0]` is the initialization vector at cycle 0.

Comment: "bit" is not a datatype in Python. You might have a list of one-character strings, `["1", "0", "0", "1", "0"]`. Or you might have a list of integers that happen to be restricted to `0` and `1`. With all this I'm assuming you say "array" because you're not used to Python. Or maybe you have a numpy array? Or you might have a numpy `uint8` array created with `numpy.packbits`. Or you might have a five-character string `"10010"`, which is not exactly either a list or an array, but is a sequence. EDIT: I just saw the edit. Thank you.

Comment: EDIT2: Actually scratch that, the first two `X=...` lines contradict each other. The first line says `X` is a 100-character string. The second line says it is a list of integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a function that XORs two lists of integers (the IV and part of the data) and generates the XORed version of it. The function can be implemented using the operator `^` in python

I am using here the 'bits' as integers, but if you need to use strings, you can just convert each char using `int()` before calling the function

```
def get_new_iv_value(prev_iv, X):
    new_iv = [x ^ y for (x,y) in zip(prev_iv, X)]
    return new_iv
```

Here is one example of how to use this function to calculate a new IV for each 5 elements of X

```
# Create X with 10 'bits' (integers with values 0 or 1)
X = [random.randint(0,1) for i in range(10)]

# Set initial IV with size 5
IV = [1,0,1,0,1]

# This will calculate one new IV for each 5 elements in X
for n in range(0, 100, 5): 
    IV = get_new_iv_value(IV, X[n:n+5])
```

The result is this:

```
IV[0] = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
X = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
IV[1] = IV[0] + X[0:5]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1] = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1] + [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
IV[2] = IV[1] + X[5:10]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0] = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1] + [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: @klaus.If I have the list of IV:`[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
                                  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]`How to combine it back to [0, 0, 0, 1, 0,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]

Comment: You can use  '+' to concatenate two lists:
```a = [0,0,0,1,0]```
```b=[1,0,0,0,1]```
```c = a + b```
```$ c = [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]```